'Cannot convert value "" to type'
I'm having an issue trying to remove departed users that are in a CSV file. There is too many for me to go into them individually and remove access.  The code below is what I have come up with but I keep getting the error 'Cannot convert value "" to type'. Full error below Powershell code. I'm not sure why it's passing a null value. The powershell code is below with some redacted items. Any help would be greatly appreceiated.
$users = Import-Csv C:\users\__xxxxxxxx\Downloads\mailbox_cleanup_090624.csv
$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -Filter 'customattribute3 -eq "[yyy]"' 

foreach($user in $users){
    $user_in_mailboxes = foreach($mailbox in $mailboxes){ Get-MailboxPermission $mailbox -User $user}

    foreach($user_in_mailbox in $user_in_mailboxes) {
        Remove-MailboxPermission $user_in_mailbox -User $user -AccessRights Fullaccess -Confirm:$false
        Remove-RecipientPermission $user_in_mailbox -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee $user -Confirm:$false
    }
}

Write-ErrorMessage : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'User'. Cannot convert value "" to type 
"Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.SecurityPrincipalIdParameter". Error: "Parameter values of type 
Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.SecurityPrincipalIdParameter can't be empty. Specify a value, and try again. 
(Parameter 'identity')"
At C:\Users\__xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_uwaajssr.23n\tmpEXO_uwaajssr.23n.psm1:1205 char:13
+             Write-ErrorMessage $ErrorObject
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-MailboxPermission], ParameterTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=PH7PR19MB6852,RequestId=85f202a1-8c41-a70c-2540-72dc0cd30369,TimeStamp=Fri, 06 Sep 20 
   24 20:58:11 GMT],Write-ErrorMessage

This is the original one where I was entering the name individually, this worked fine.
$user = 'zzzz'
$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -Filter 'customattribute3 -eq "[yyy]"' | Get-MailboxPermission -User $user
$mailboxes

foreach($mailbox in $mailboxes) {
    Remove-MailboxPermission $mailbox -User $user -AccessRights Fullaccess -Confirm:$false
    Remove-RecipientPermission $mailbox -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee $user -Confirm:$false
    }


Each $user is a [PSCustomObject] which properties named equal to the column header names of your mailbox_cleanup_090624.csv file. Meaning that it should be something like -User $user.<property/column name>, e.g.: -User $user.user.

You have an empty string which cannot be converted to a type.  Are there any blank lines in the CSV?  Make sure first and last line in file are not blank.
